# Service Accounts, web OAuth and the Directory API

Tags: python, api, oauth, google-oauth

I'm having issues with the Directory API + Service Accounts (Google APIs). This is my current setup:

1. A web page has an OAuth2 login link like this: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&state=%2Fprofile&redirect_uri=##REDIR##&response_type=code&client_id=##CLIENTID##&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fadmin.directory.user.readonly`
2. Users log in there, authorizing the app to access the Directory API in read-only mode on their behalf.
3. I then try to retrieve the users of the domain of a given user (by knowing its email address), using the Directory API.

Python code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import httplib2

CLIENT_ID = "xzxzxzxzxzxz.apps.googleusercontent.com"
APP_EMAIL = "xzxzxzxzxzxz@developer.gserviceaccount.com"

SCOPES = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly')

f = file('key.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(APP_EMAIL, key, SCOPES, sub="user@example.com")

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

directory_service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
users = directory_service.users().list(domain="example.com").execute()
print users
```

I have also tried setting `sub="user@example.com"` to the app owner like this `sub="appowner@company.com"`, to no avail.

Another thing I have tried is not using impersonation at all (ie. removing the sub=xx part), which leads me to this error:

> apiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=example.com&alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">

Using impersonation always yields me this. I have verified it has to do with the scopes and the api which I try to call:

> oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied

Now, the actual questions:

1. Should I be using service accounts? For me, it is the most convenient way as I don't have to be storing tokens which can be outdated altogether.
2. If service accounts are the way to go, what am I doing wrong in the way I use them? Impersonation with either the Google Apps administrator account (which logs in via OAuth web) or the app owner account does not seem to work.